# What programming language was Office 2011 for Mac written with?

Tags: c#, macos, ms-office

I was curious if it was written in objective C or possibly Microsoft was considering taking mono more seriously? Any .NET is office 2011 for mac?

Comment: In truth, I would doubt that much if any of the office products will be written in .net in the future.  I could be wrong, but I keep hearing that there is too much legacy code in C, C++ to effectively convert it. I would guess this includes those for the Mac.  Couple this with the fact that Microsoft doesn't own the code for mono, I don't think they would rely on it.

Comment: The sensible thing would be to port the C++ files and rewrite the UI in objective-c mixing in .NET would be brainless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same language as previous versions.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office) C++ and Objective-C.

It would be insane for Microsoft to rewrite it from scratch in a new language.
(This is also why Office for Windows isn't written in C#)